# WebView.zoomIn() not working before rendering view

Tags: android, android-webview

I am calling wv.zoomIn() in my fragment's onCreateView, and it is having no effect.

Full story ...

My fragment contains a slider which I use to programmatically zoomIn/zoomOut a webview. This is working fine.

I now want to store the last used zoom level, and apply it to the webview next time it is displayed. So in the onCreateView I am retrieving the zoom level and calling zoomIn an appropriate number of times.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater...
...
if (savedZoom > defaultZoom) { 
 for (int i=defaultZoom; i< savedZoom; i++) {
   MyLog.d("zooming in");   // appears x times in log as expected
   boolean zoominResult = wv.zoomIn();
   MyLog.d("zoominResult = "+zoominResult); // shows zoomIn returns FALSE
 }
}
```

The logs confirm that wv.zoomIn() is being called the correct number of times, but the displayed webview is still at the default zoom.

Any suggestions such as a way to call the zoomIn() post-render, or an alternative way to preserve and restore the zoom settings of the webview?

Comment: is `zoomIn()` returning `false` per documentation? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#zoomIn()

Comment: It's returning false. I've updated the question with the additional info.

Answer (score 2):

**I think this code will help:**

```
webView.clearView();
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("< your URL >");

int scale = (int) (100 * webView.getScale());

webView.setInitialScale(scale);

webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of zooming the `webview` in a loop,
Try

```
wv.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(savedZoom-defaultZoom);
```

Also, in order to enable zoom on the webView, add the following code:

```
wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

You may also try

```
int zoomLevel=(defaultZoom/savedZoom)*100;
wv.setInitialScale(zoomLevel);
```

Comment: In your first suggestion, what is "savedZoom" ?

Answer (score 1):

just set initial scale :

```
webView.setInitialScale(500);
```

where 500 can be your any saved zoom value.